# Sorting in Filed Collection Views

Tags: views, entities

I am using [Field Collection Views](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection_views) in Drupal and everything works fine, except Sorting. I am able to rearrange the Field Collection items in Edit form using both drag-and-drop also manually using Row weights option.

I would like the the Field Collection View results to be sorted by this Row weight, could you please guide how I could acheive this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a very easy workaround via DraggableViews module and it works just fine.. the step-by-step instructions could be found here..

[Custom Sort Drupal Content with the Draggable Views Module](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/custom-sort-drupal-content-draggable-views-module)

Thanks to the Author - Kronda Adair. :-)

Answer (score 3):

This could be achieved by creating a relationship, and using Delta to sort. Let us say that the field collection field's name in the entity is field_slides.

Create a relationship with '**Field collection item: Entity with the Slides (field_slides)**'. Check the box for - Require this relationship

Comment: This worked for me. I created a relationship for the field collection first, then created another relationship with the individual field collection field.

Comment: +1, after creating the relationship, it does the magic. I did not need to add the sort criteria. Adding sort criteria shows duplicate record for me as delta for that field collection field is different for a same record.